# Simplify strategies: Convince sympy that complicated term is zero

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy

What are good strategies/heuristics to convince sympy that a complicated term including trigonometric functions is 0?

For example, let's consider the following term:
`-2*a**2*b*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**(-12.0)*(a**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9.0 + b**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9.0 + c**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9.0 - (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**10.0)*sin(0.5*sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2))**2`

[Wolfram alpha agrees with me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) that it should be zero.

I tried `sympy.simplify` as well as `sympy.trigsimp`, but not sure what to try next.

I'm using python 3.6.3 and sympy 1.1.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No special effort is needed; just avoid floating point numbers, representing them by integers or rationals. Floating point numbers are an obstacle to symbolic math because floating point arithmetics doesn't work like regular arithmetics. (The Python 2 habit of making everything a float so that division works right really needs to be unlearned to use SymPy effectively.)

```
e  = -2*a**2*b*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**(-12)*(a**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9 + b**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9 + c**2*(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**9 - (a**2 + b**2 + c**2)**10)*sin(sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)/2)**2
e.simplify()
```

returns 0.

Besides changing 12.0 to 12, etc I also got changed `0.5*sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)` to `sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)/2`. Other options here include replacing 0.5 by

- `Rational(1, 2)`, or
- `Rational('0.5')`, or
- `S.Half` (SymPy's built-in 1/2 object)
- `S(1)/2` (S turns 1 into SymPy integer, which makes the division by 2 go by SymPy rules instead of Python rules).

Comment: is there a way to use `numexpr` ?